# Put one dinamic object with assets in laravel

Tags: image, laravel, object, laravel-5, assets

Hi i dont know how put img with assets. 
I have this

```
{{asset('Articulos/{{$Articulo->path}}')}}
```

but i have error 
**syntax error, unexpected '}'**

can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
{{ asset('Articulos/' . $Articulo->path) }}
```

Comment: oooo Perfect!! thaks!!